# How to remove System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action link that looks like;

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Model.forumItem.title, "ViewForumItem", new { Id = Model.forumItem.id, title=Model.forumItem.title.Replace(" ", "-") })%>
```

However the url it produces is;

```
http://localhost:50756/Home/ViewForumItem/System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter/Clappy?Id=15
```

What can I do to make it look like;

```
http://localhost:50756/Home/ViewForumItem/15/Clappy
```

Much like SO does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a Route Definition like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyNewRoute", // Route name
    "Home/{action}/{id}/{title}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", title = "" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

make sure of your parameter keys in your ActionLink does exist in your Route Definition and in the same case since it is a case sensitive for example the `id` must have small case if you write it in small case in your Route Definition.